# Drawing human or animal bodies which aren't too realistic

Tags: drawing, painting

[image]

The girl in this picture doesn't look like a "real" girl but she does look 
like a human female without visible defects (improperly placed eye/arm) etc.

What do I need to learn to draw and paint such figures which represent humans or animals but aren't be too realistic?

Will learning about the number of bones/muscles and their placements be required here?

I found this picture on internet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to draw objects (humans, animals, or whatever) that are stylised (i.e. aren't too realistic) you need to learn how to draw them realistically first.

The idea is the same as “learn the rules first in order to know how to break them properly” (sorry for the cliché). You need to understand your subject (what it actually is) in order to reveal it in the way you desire (stylise it). Take a look at what the artists did for [the development of the Bambi character](http://andreasdeja.blogspot.bg/2014/05/deer-development.html).

You can do it the other way round, as people often go for as it brings quick and somewhat satisfactory results, i.e. chose a style and learn to draw this way (like 'how to draw chibi manga girls'). However, understanding the style and not understanding the subject won’t get you far with your art.

Comment: Hi, I just saw a couple of anonymous edits proposed for some answers of yours. If they are your edits, please log in and you'll be able to edit without needing approval. If you accidentally made two accounts, you can merge them using the "Contact" link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I love the link to bambi development, it was fascinating! I'll also add that studying how other artists draw can help you in understanding basic shapes, where they go, when something gets shaded or doesn't ect. You can also use the "sausage person" method - where you draw oval sausage shapes instead of the actual figure - to help you learn proportions, which will often be critical to drawing in even unrealistic styles.